# Full background change jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm about to make a portfolio where the background changes after what link you click
But i can only get it to work with one image

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('img.thumb').click(function() {
  $('#bgimg').fadeOut(500, function() {
   $(this).css('background-image', 'url(img/myfoto.jpg)');
  }).fadeIn(500);
 });
});
```

But i would like it to work so when i click the .thumb it takes the src from there and use that as the url

Like this: (but it dont work)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('img.thumb').click(function() {
  $('#bgimg').fadeOut(500, function() {
   $(this).css('background-image', '$('.thumb').attr('src')');
  }).fadeIn(500);
 });
});
```

Comment: your syntax is all screwy >> $(this).css('background-image', $('.thumb').attr('src')); << use that

Comment: It just fades out and fade the same image back

Answer (score 0):

First, you're creating a string where you don't mean to. This would be the correct line of code:

```js
$(this).css('background-image', $('.thumb').attr('src'));
```

Even better would be to use `this`, as it is the reference to the actual image clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('img.thumb').click(function() {
  var bgSrc = $(this).attr('src'); // get the source of the image clicked
  $('#bgimg').fadeOut(500, function() {
   $(this).css('background-image', bgSrc); // and apply it to #bgimg
  }).fadeIn(500);
 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer but unfortunately it didn't work.
It just fades out and in again

Comment: @MatsKruger I'd suggest you show your markup and a live example of your code.